unordered_map с транзакциями
Кто-нибудь знает в C++ удобные/известные хеш-таблицы с транзакциями?
Что-то похожее на unordered_map<string, string>, но еще есть commit() и rollback()?
P.S. Я уже написал свою и хотел бы сравнить результаты: Хеш-таблица с транзакциями.
Пока ders::mem_db заметно быстрее unordered_map<string, string>, но это не совсем корректное сравнение.

Непонятно, что тут подразумевается под "commit() и rollback()". unordered_map и так имеет что-то вроде транзаций. Например если при вставке элемента что-то идет не так, то гарантируется откат до исходного состояния. "ders::mem_db заметно быстрее unordered_map" - сильное заявление
